# Polynomial rings where number of generators is not known in sympy

Tags: python, sympy

I'm trying to create a coordinate ring of an algebraic set (where the algebrais set is specified by some set of polynomials in arbitrary variables over a field).

So I'm using Sympy's  `poly_ring()` function

It's usually used to create coordinate rings when you already know the generators of the ideal you want to define it for, for example;

```
CoordinateRing = QQ.poly_ring(x,y,z) / [y**2 - z*x, xy*2 + z]
```

But I want to make no assumption on the number of variables used in the defining polynomials for my algebraic sets. So I wrote a function `get_symbols()` that extracts all the symbols used in the defining polynomials. **Is there a way to set the generators for `poly_ring()` without having to list them as parameters?**

```
from sympy import * 

class AlgebraicSet(object):
    def __init__(self, polynomials,field):

        self.polynomials = polynomials
        self.field = field 

    def get_symbols(self):

        symbols = set()

        for f in self.polynomials:
            symbols = set(symbols | f.atoms(Symbol)) 

        return symbols

    def get_cooridinate_ring(self):
        return self.field.poly_ring(self.get_symbols(),order="ilex") / self.polynomials
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code wasn't working for me, but I found using `old_poly_ring` instead of `poly_ring` did the trick:

```
from sympy import * 

class AlgebraicSet(object):
    def __init__(self, polynomials,field):

        self.polynomials = polynomials
        self.field = field 

    def get_symbols(self):

        symbols = set()

        for f in self.polynomials:
            symbols = set(symbols | f.atoms(Symbol)) 

        return symbols

    def get_coordinate_ring(self):
        poly_ring = self.field.old_poly_ring(*self.get_symbols(),order="ilex")
        return poly_ring / poly_ring.ideal(*self.polynomials)

from sympy.abc import x, y, z

print AlgebraicSet([y**2 - z*x, x*y*2 + z], QQ).get_coordinate_ring()
```

Comment: Hey Thanks a ton! Worked like a charm!